# Presenting two data frames on the same facetted ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two data frames that I am struggling to combine into one plot. A reproduction of the first data frame is given below, followed by the code to generate a forest plot of the data, facetted for different groups of variables. The `geom_points` are filled if the p.value is <0.05, and unfilled if otherwise.

```
library(tidyverse)

##data frame
df1 <- tibble('outcome.var' = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'),
   'coefficient' = c(-0.08, -0.01, -0.06, 0.02, 0.01, 0.02, -0.08, -0.1, 0.1, 0.2),
   'conf.low' = c(-0.12, -0.03, -0.09, 0.01, 0.02,  0.01, -0.10, -0.2, 0.05, 0.1),
   'conf.high' = c(-0.05, 0.02, -0.03, 0.03, -0.01, 0.04, -0.06, 0, 0.2, 0.3),
   'p.value' =c(0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.10, 0.02, 0.13, 0.11, 0.01, 0.01, 0.04)) %>%
  mutate(significant = ifelse(p.value > 0.05, 'P > 0.05', 'P < 0.05'),
         label = case_when(
      .$outcome.var %in% c('A', 'B', 'C') ~ '1',
      .$outcome.var %in% c('D', 'E', 'F') ~ '2',
      .$outcome.var %in% c('G', 'H') ~ '3',
      .$outcome.var %in% c('I', 'J') ~ '4'))
```

The creation of the `label` variable is to enable correct facetting in the plot.

**Updated to include variable conversion to a factor**

```
df1$outcome.var <- df1$outcome.var %>%
    as.factor() %>%
     fct_relevel(., 'B', 'C', 'A', 'F', 'D', 'E', 'H', 'G', 'J', 'I') %>%
     fct_recode(., 'Bb' = 'B',
         'Cc' = 'C',
         'Aa' = 'A',
         'Ff' = 'F',
         'Dd' = 'D',
         'Ee' = 'E',
         'Hh' = 'H',
         'Gg' = 'G',
         'Jj' = 'J',
         'Ii' = 'I') %>%
     fct_rev()

p1 <- ggplot(data = df1, aes(outcome.var, coefficient)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), shape = 32) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = significant), fill = 'white') +
  geom_hline(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, yintercept = 0, colour = "grey40", size = 0.5, linetype = "solid") +
  geom_hline(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, yintercept = c(-0.15, -0.10, -0.05, 0.05, 0.10), colour = "grey85", size = 0.5, linetype = "longdash") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey95")) +
  scale_y_continuous('Coefficient') +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(19, 21)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c('black', 'black')) + 
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines")) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  xlab(NULL) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(label ~ ., scales = "free", space = "free", switch = "x") +
  theme(strip.text.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(face = 'bold'))
```

I have a second data frame `df2`, which has an identical structure to `df1`, just with different data values. How can I code my plot so that it contains both the `geom_point`and `geom_pointrange` for both `df1`and `df2`, but the `df2`points in different colours. Ideally the points and point ranges should be slightly offset vertically from one another so that they don't overlap on the plot.

Comment: Could you provide an example of `df2` just like you did for `df1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide the data frame `df2`, so let me create one with random values.

```
df2 <-
    df1 %>%
    mutate(
        coefficient = coefficient + rnorm(1, sd=0.1),
        conf.low = coefficient - 0.05,
        conf.high = coefficient + 0.05,
        significant = ifelse(p.value > 0.05, 'P > 0.05', 'P < 0.05'))
```

Now I add a variable `dataset` to keep track which values come from which dataset, and combine the two data frames into one called `df`.

```
df1 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(dataset = 'original')

df2 <- df2 %>%
    mutate(dataset = 'alternative')

df <- bind_rows(df1, df2)
```

Your graph can be created using the `color` aesthetic and `position_dodge()` in the `geom_pointrange()` and `geom_point()` commands.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(outcome.var, coefficient, color=dataset)) +
    geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), shape = 32, position=position_dodge(width=0.5)) +
    geom_point(aes(shape = significant), fill = 'white', position=position_dodge(width=0.5)) +
    geom_hline(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, yintercept = 0, colour = "grey40", size = 0.5, linetype = "solid") +
    geom_hline(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, yintercept = c(-0.15, -0.10, -0.05, 0.05, 0.10), colour = "grey85", size = 0.5, linetype = "longdash") +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey95")) +
    scale_y_continuous('Coefficient') +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(19, 21)) +
    # scale_colour_manual(values = c('black', 'black')) + 
    theme(panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines")) +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
    xlab(NULL) +
    coord_flip() +
    facet_grid(label ~ ., scales = "free", space = "free", switch = "x") +
    theme(strip.text.y = element_blank()) +
    theme(legend.text = element_text(face = 'bold'))
```

[image: Resulting figure]

Comment: Nice first answer :) this is slightly more readable than the other method which contains pipes within pipes.

Comment: Thanks, and thanks for including the graph and simplifying the code :)

Comment: @David  and @Mikey Thanks for your solution. In my code, I forgot to include that the `outcome.var` is formatted as a factor to ensure the order of labels on the y-axis is what I require. This order is neither alphabetical or non-alphabetical. When I apply your solution to my own data, the points and confidence intervals plotted for both `df1` and `df2` are identical. Is this likely caused by the additional step of converting to a factor and how can I address this?

Comment: I cannot see why the label being a factor would result in identical dataframes for `df1` and `df2` . Check your dataframes before you merge the two. This problem seems distinctly different to this question so if you cannot find a solution to your problem you should post this as a separate question.

Comment: @Mikey I think I figured it out. If I set `group = dataset` in first line of the plot call then it appears to prevent the data points dissociating from the centre of the confidence interval line.

Comment: @Paul, I just combined your updated code (minus the plot) and added the code in the answer and it plots just fine, with different values for the random data. The labels on the y axis start with `Bb` on top and end with `Ii`. For me, this works without setting the `group` aesthetic.

Comment: @David Apologies for late response. Yes, it works for me too now without setting `group` (I don't know what I was doing wrong before), and also works with my actual data set. I still need to set `group` in my actual data set to prevent the few instances of the points dissociating from the confidence intervals.